# Is $(0,0)$ is a singular point of $f(x,y) = x$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have a little confusion regarding the following statement from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_point_of_a_curve#Algebraic_curves_in_the_plane):

> The singular points are those points on the curve where both partial derivatives vanish

I can see that for the straight line $x=0$ if I assume $f(x,y)=x$ then $f=f_x=f_y=0$ at $(0,0).$ Is it then justified to say $(0,0)$ is a singular point of the above line?

Comment: But the partials are $1$.

Comment: $f_x=1$ again!! Try with $f(x,y) \equiv 0$.

Comment: When you say "*then*" and follow with what you think $f_x$ and $f_y$ are, be sure that your calculations are indeed correct.  Go back and remember your rules of differentiation.  For a less trivial example, perhaps try with $f(x,y)=xy$ at which point you have $f_x = y$ and $f_y=x$, which indeed at the point $(0,0)$ these will both be equal and zero.  In both your original question and the edit, as mentioned, your partial derivatives are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x,y) = x$, then $f_x = 1$, $f_y = 0$. So $(0,0)$ is not a critical point. And in fact, there are no critical points, as the $x$ partial derivative never vanishes.